# Layering two Shapes in Android

Tags: android, xml, shapes, seekbar

I'm trying to create a custom thumbnail for a seek bar, and I want it to look like an orange circle with a white "glowing" effect around the edges. I'm trying to achieve this by layering two circles on each other, one with a white-to-transparent gradient, and then the smaller orange circle on top like so:

[image]

Here is the xml file:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            <size
                android:height="30dp"
                android:width="30dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@android:color/white"
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gradientRadius="20dp"
                android:type="radial"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/app_light_orange"
                android:endColor="@color/app_orange"
                android:gradientRadius="18dp"
                android:type="radial"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

However, when I run my app, the thumbnail just turns out as an orange circle with a 30dp radius. How would I fix it to get my desired result?

Comment: Add an image of your requirement

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps

[Halo Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDQfV.png)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="100dp" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:centerX="50%p"
            android:centerY="50%p"
            android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
            android:gradientRadius="50%p"
            android:startColor="#00FFFFFF"
            android:type="radial" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="20dp" android:left="20dp" android:bottom="20dp" android:right="20dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="100dp" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    </shape>
</item>
```